# Is it possible to write and edit etc/default/unicorn using FTP ? RoR, Ubuntu 12.10 server Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I am trying to follow this guide : https://digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-1-click-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-10-with-digitalocean
I am at this part :

Now modify your PATH in /etc/default/unicorn:

```
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin:/home/unicorn/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:$
```

Since I changed to ruby-2.0.0-p247, I would like to modify this in the unicorn folder, however I do not know how. Everytime I try to modify it using filezilla it fails the transfer :

```
Erreur : /etc/default/unicorn: open for write: permission denied 
Erreur : Echec du transfert du fichier
```

and typing `PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin:/home/unicorn/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin:$` 
as root in the terminal does not seem to do anything because the file remains the same. So how do I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that FileZilla is failing because you're logging in as a non-root user for the transfer, and `/etc/default/unicorn` requires root permissions to edit.

Meanwhile, just retyping your PATH in the terminal won't help. You have to edit the `/etc/default/unicorn` file, change the line in there, and save the file. You need to use a text editor - try `nano`, which is often installed on minimally-configured Linux boxes. Log into your server and try this:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/unicorn
```

Find the line with PATH in it, edit it, and use `control-O` to write out the changes (see the help at the bottom of the `nano` screen) then `control-X` to exit `nano`.